# The map cannot see data from the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After installing the map on my site

```
state={
items:[{
      "X": 13.6155611,
      "Y": 51.0331258
    },
    ],
}
componentDidMount() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
    });
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
      var obj = this.state.items[i];
      let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(obj.X, obj.Y);
      new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(myLatlng)
        .addTo(map);
    }
}

 render() {
    return (
        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} />
)}
```

I want to display markers after entering x and y, and read this data from the table. I have 2 inputs, one for X and the other for Y after clicking "add"
I add this data to the table and I have 2 objects, etc ... but only one marker from state.items is displayed on the map, although I have more coordinates in the table. Please help

Comment: Bit confused since I see the state not being used during the render. Not exactly sure what you intend for that ref also. All that said I can see you are looping and adding markers in componentDidMount. I also see this map you generate isn't bound to state at all. You'll probably want this in state and passed down to your component. Also when you do this, if you mutate the object and even call setState, it will not register as a new object and therefore the render method won't be called. There are ways to get that though.

Comment: what are these ways?

Comment: You can clone the before passing it to setState via Object.assign or you could store some sort of incrementing id in state and increment along with your map state forcing a render.